# Creating a function to sort particular data in a text.txt

Tags: python, function, sorting, file-handling

I am trying to sort out the first three elements in a text file using a function.  I was able to do it correctly with some simpler code but I am not sure why it won't work within the function.  It won't update my empty list I created for some reason.  But in the working code, that isn't a function, it works just fine.

This is the working code:

```
mytags = []
mylines = []
with open ('iphone_07_18_1.annot', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        mylines.append(line)
    for element in mylines:
        mytags.append(element[:3])
print(mytags)
```

This is my function that isn't working:

```
#Open&close files, read file and set the variables.
fhand = open('iphone_07_18_1.annot', 'r')
myfile = fhand.read()
mylines = []
mytags = []
fhand.close()

def Tags():     #function to create a list to append from
    for line in myfile:
         mylines.append(line)
    for element in mylines:
         mytags.append(element[:3])
    print(mytags)
Tags()
```

Comment: It's not function. It's the difference between iterating over the file handle  with `for line in myfile` and calling `read()` on it. `fhand.read()` won't split lines, it just makes one big string so when you iterate over it you get each character. Try `f.read().splitlines()` or `f.readlines()` depending on how you want to handle the newline characters in each line.